# Show that $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{∞} = \frac{{(-1)}^k}{(2 k + 1)!}{{(x)}^{2k+1}}$ converges uniformly on...

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Does anyone know how to show that

$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{∞} \frac{{(-1)}^k}{(2 k + 1)!}{{(x)}^{2k+1}}$$

converges uniformly on $[-a,a]$ for every $a>0$, but not uniformly on $R$?

I believe it has something to do with the Weierstrass-M test?

Answer (score 1):

**hint:**
$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{∞}  \frac{{(-1)}^k}{(2 k + 1)!}{{(x)}^{2k+1}}=\sin(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

This expansion converges to the sine function on the real line.  Each partial sum is a polynomial, which becomes large as $x\to\infty$, whilst the sine function bounces back and forth between $-1$ and $1$.  If they converged uniformly, the result could not be bounded as $x\to\infty$.